# Negative margins questions and inconsistencies

Tags: css

My first question is with the trick of  ignoring the parent element's padding.
I understand that negative TOP and LEFT margin moves that element farther in that direction where it can possibly move out of its parent element.

What i'm really confused is with negative RIGHT margins.
I suppose that it makes an element wider by a specified amount.
And with negative BOTTOM margins. It makes the element shorter.

Second question is that large negative margin-bottom seem to display inconsistently.

Here's the demo

http://jsbin.com/ehawey/1/edit

Answer (score 5):

For block elements, what you describe with horizontal margins is correct. For vertical margins on block elements, it is slightly different.

Imagine how you'd lay out a bunch of boxes vertically with no spacing between them. You'd start with a Y of zero, and then for each block, you'd place it at that position and then advance the Y value by its height.

Now we extend that to include spacing. A simplified view of how the CSS model works is by starting with a Y value of zero, as before, but before placing a box, adding the top margin, and after placing a box, adding the bottom margin. The way it actually works is a little more complex as margins collapse in some cases. Anyway, this simplified model is enough to describe why the height does not change: a negative bottom margin will affect placement of the next box, but will not make the box itself bigger.

Comment: @georgefox sorry. but i don't fully understand what you mean on relative with the bottom margin of h3 tag. Because even if i remove the margin of h3 tag or completely remove the h3 tag yet still the same result.